# alphabetical pagination in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, rubygems, alphabetical

I'm searching a gem for Rails for alphabetical pagination. I wish I could have a list of first letters found in the result (I mean, if there is no row beginning with 'a', I don't want the 'a' to be display on the pagination links). Is this kind of gem already exists?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12):

This wouldn't be too hard to create at all, for example if you had a `find`, maybe like:

```
@all_words = Word.select("words.word")
```

…which returned a result a result set such as a list of words like this:

```
["alphabet", "boy", "day", "donkey", "ruby", "rails", "iPad"]
```

…the you could do this:

```
@all_words.collect {|word| word[0,1]}.uniq.sort
```

which would return:

```
["a", "b", "d", "r", "i"]
```

The `.collect {|word| word[0,1]}` stores the first letter of each word into a new array whilst `uniq` filters out the unique letters and `sort` sorts these alphabetically.

Simply assign this to a variable and you can use it in your view like so:

```
<ul>
<% @first_letters.each do |letter| %>
    <%= content_tag :li, link_to(letter, words_pagination_url(letter), :title => "Pagination by letter: #{letter}") %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Your controller action could then decide what to do with the param from the pagination if one is passed in:

```
def index
    if params[:letter]
        @words = Word.by_letter(params[:letter])
    else
        @words = Word.all
    end
end
```

And then the scope in your model would look something like:

```
scope :by_letter,
        lambda { |letter| {
            :conditions => ["words.word LIKE ?", "#{letter}%"]
        }}
```

Your routes require something like:

```
match "words(/:letter)" => "words#index", :as => words_pagination
```

I haven't tested this all the way through but it should set you on the right path.

Comment: Is there a way to do the first part by SQL?

Comment: what if we are talking of tens of thousands of words? not sure this scales beyond a few dozen...

Comment: If you have tens of thousands of words that likely cover the entire alphabet then why not just output the alphabet and link to each letter: `("a".."z").to_a`

Answer (score 5):

To get a dynamic select from the appropriate table, you can use a dynamic SQL finder.

In this example, we select from a table named 'albums', and fabricate a column 'name' to hold the values.  These will be returned in the 'Album' model object.  Change any of these names to suit your needs.

```
Album.find_by_sql("SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(name,1,1) AS 'name' FROM albums ORDER BY 1")
```

Note that you can't use the Album model objects for *anything* except querying the 'name' field.  This is because we've given this object a lobotomy by only populating the 'name' field - there's not even a valid 'id' field associated!

Answer (score 5):

I've created an alphabetical pagination gem here:
https://github.com/lingz/alphabetical_paginate

For anyone still having issues in this domain.