# Alphabetically paginate words in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I am building a rails dictionary application. I have defined and created my whole dictionary in a simple table that draws from a .txt document via a buffer where the view looks like this:

```
<% @words.each do |word| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= word.word %></td>
    <td><%= word.wordtype %></td>
    <td><%= word.description %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', word %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def index
  @words = Word.all
end
```

How do I go about adding an alphabetical index at the top of the page that will display only the words for that letter? I am new to rails and ruby so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `alphabetical_paginate` gem](https://github.com/lingz/alphabetical_paginate) helps you implement this.

If you wish to not use a gem, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590321/326543) has some tips that you can borrow.